# slotProps defined with slot-scope does not work with v-if in vue.js 2.6.0

Tags: vue.js

I just updated to vue.js 2.6.0 from 2.5.21 and some of my pages stopped working.

Eventually I found out the problem is in the following:

```
Vue.component('foo' , {
    data : function() { return { a : 42 /*this is computed dynamically in real life*/ } } ,
    template : `<div><slot v-bind:a="a">Default Text</slot></div>`
});
```

and I use it like so

```
<foo><template  slot-scope="slotProps" v-if="slotProps.a==42"> Fourty two</template></foo>
```

Basically I want to use the passed template only when a is 42 otherwise leave the default value.

using vue.js v 2.5.21 I get "Fourty Two" when a is 42 and "Default Text" otherwise

Using vue.js v 2.6.0 I get an error

```
Property or method "slotProps" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

Is that a regression introduced in vue 2.6.0 or was I using it incorrectly but due to a bug in 2.5.21 it was working as I expected it to?
In the latter case what is the recommended way of using a different template conditionally depending on the value of a?

PS: I know I am supposed to move to using v-slot eventually but 2.6.0 was not supposed to break backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a regression that was introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/commit/5851961ca320a423003bd32fecb488f230dcd854). It was thankfully fixed about an hour ago in [version 2.6.2](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/commit/44a4ca33b95070e9aa53c6924479519d86dd9b36).

```js
Vue.component('foo', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      a: 42 /*this is computed dynamically in real life*/
    }
  },
  template: `<div><slot v-bind:a="a">Default Text</slot></div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <foo><template slot-scope="slotProps" v-if="slotProps.a==42"> Fourty two</template></foo>
</div>
```

Comment: omg  I can't believe they releases a version with such issues! I spent like an hour trying to find out what is wrong!!